# Webpack module federation - module instance duplicated by import

Tags: webpack, webpack-module-federation

I'm building a React app with plugin support using module federation:

- It consist of a **host app** and multiple **plugins** (remote apps).
- Plugins are imported dynamically into the host app.
- Host app exposes some of its functionality to plugins.

```js
// host app config
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
   name: "host",
   exposes: {
       // Host API used by plugins
       ".": "./src/api"
   },
   // ...
}
```

Now, I can import the API inside a plugin

```js
import {FooBar} from "host";
```

and I can also import the same thing within the host app:

```js
import {FooBar} from "./src/api";
```

The problem is that **these imports are not resolved as a singleton**. Host app and the plugin receives each own unique instance of the imported module. This is a problem because:

- I need to access a global state through the API.
- If there is a class shared through the API, then its instances created inside host/plugin are not equal (in terms of `instanceof` operator).

Plugin:

```js
import {FooBar} from "host";

export const fooBar = new FooBar;
```

Host app:

```js
import {FooBar} from "./src/api";

import("plugin").then(plugin => {
    plugin.fooBar instanceof FooBar; // false
});
```

Question: **How to configure module federation for this to work? Or is this behavior a bug?**

I have also reproduced it in [this repository](https://github.com/jpikl/webpack-host-remote).

**EDIT**: After some investigation, the cause seems to be that `main.js` chunk and `remoteEntry.js` of the host app have separate `__webpack_module_cache__` for module resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a custom webpack plugin that fixes the described behavior by creating a shared module cache between `main.js` chunk and `remoteEntry.js`.

```js
import webpack, {RuntimeGlobals} from "webpack";
import {ConcatSource, OriginalSource} from "webpack-sources";

const {Template} = webpack;
const {JavascriptModulesPlugin} = webpack.javascript;

const PLUGIN_NAME = "SharedModuleCachePlugin";

export default class SharedModuleCachePlugin {
    constructor(options = {}) {
        this.cacheVar = options.cacheVar || "__shared_module_cache__";
    }

    apply(compiler) {
        compiler.hooks.compilation.tap(PLUGIN_NAME, compilation => {
            const compilationHooks = JavascriptModulesPlugin.getCompilationHooks(compilation);
            compilationHooks.renderStartup.tap(PLUGIN_NAME, startupSource => {
                const cacheCode = Template.asString([
                    "if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {",
                    Template.indent([
                        `if (!window.${this.cacheVar}) {`,
                        Template.indent(`window.${this.cacheVar} = {};`),
                        "}",
                        "",
                        `__webpack_module_cache__ = window.${this.cacheVar};`,
                        `${RuntimeGlobals.moduleCache} = window.${this.cacheVar};`,
                    ]),
                    "}",
                ]);
                const cacheSource = new OriginalSource(cacheCode, "webpack/shared-module-cache");
                return new ConcatSource(cacheSource, startupSource);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

This needs to be used only in host app webpack configuration.